# Checkboxes for Hide/Show columns in Vue.js table not working properly

Tags: javascript, vue.js, vuejs2, bootstrap-vue

I made a vue.js bootstrap table for loading some data from local JSON files.
I'm trying to implement show/hide columns via checkboxes.
I think I've solved most of the problem, but the problem is when I hide a column and then press on that same checkbox again (to make column visible again) I lose the order of table (that column becomes last column) and so on.
For example if I hide "Timestamp" column which is first table header in my table and then press to show it again it is no longer on first place, instead it gets created on last place.

https://i.stack.imgur.com/Sqk62.jpg  --> this is how app looks right now
https://codepen.io/frane_caleta/pen/KKPMKrL --> codepen of my code, you won't be able to load it without JSON file though
https://i.stack.imgur.com/fgh7o.jpg --> JSON data example

First time asking question here, so feel free to ask me if you need some more information to solve the problem :)

```html
<b-form-group label="Hide columns: ">
  <b-form-checkbox-group id="checkbox-group-1" v-model="selected" :options="fields" name="flavour-1">
  </b-form-checkbox-group>
</b-form-group>

//my table
<b-table id="myTable" 
         :small="small" 
         :bordered="bordered"
         hover head-variant="dark"  
         stacked="md" 
         :items="cptItems" 
         :fields="selected" 
         :current-page="currentPage"
         :per-page="perPage" 
         :filter="filter" 
         :sort-by.sync="sortBy" 
         :sort-desc.sync="sortDesc"
         @filtered="onFiltered"
         :tbody-tr-class="rowClass"
          v-if="selected.length > 0">
</b-table>
```

```js
//Javascript file
function initializeVue() {
  return new Vue({
        el: '#app',
        data() {
          return {
            items: data.logdatas,
            selected: [],
            fields: [{
                  text: 'Origin',
                  value: {
                    key: 'origin',
                    label: 'Origin',
                    sortable: true,
                    class: 'text-center',
                    index: 0
                  }
                },
                {
                  text: 'Timestamp',
                  value: {
                    key: 'timeStamp',
                    label: 'Timestamp',
                    sortable: true,
                    class: 'text-center',
                    index: 1
                  }
                },
                {
                  text: 'Level',
                  value: {
                    key: 'level',
                    label: 'Level',
                    sortable: true,
                    class: 'text-center',
                    index: 2
                  }
                }, ...there are 4 more fields here like this...

                //my method for creating those checkboxes
                created() {
                  this.selected = this.fields.map(field => field.value);
                }
```

Comment: Could you paste your code to codepen ?

Comment: @YigitTanriverdi Done, edited it in my post :)

Comment: could you put mock data to codepen ? @Frane Caleta

Comment: @YigitTanriverdi I've added imgur of JSON data, hopefully it helps you get the idea of what it should look like

Comment: add your json as local context of your question.

Comment: @ChristianCarrillo I'm not sure what you mean by that. It's a big json file, do you want me to paste it in another codepen or something?

Comment: The checkboxes design may work for a small number of columns. If you have more, it clutters the page. You would a columns picker UI component for better UX.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

the `selected` data is your culprit. `b-checkbox-group :selection` lists items in order of selection.

[example2](https://bootstrap-vue.js.org/docs/components/form-checkbox/)

`b-table :fields` lists columns in the order of the items.

better make a static `fields`-list and filter by `selection`.

```
// make this data or property
let columnNames = ["one", "two", "three", "infinity", "pi"];

// make this data
let selected = []

//make this computed // can be optimized 
let activeFields = columNames.filter(name => selected.includes(name))
```

```js
// more like this
export default {

  data(){
    return {
      selected: [],
      columnNames: ['name1', 'name2']
  },
  computed(){
    activeColumns(){

      return this.columnNames.filter(this.selected.includes) || []
  }
}
```

```js
const app = new Vue({
  data(){
    return {
      currentPage: 0,
      perPage: 10,
      fields: ['age', 'first_name', 'last_name'],
      //selected: [],
      selected: ['age', 'first_name', 'last_name'],
      items: [
          { age: 40, first_name: 'Dickerson', last_name: 'Macdonald' },
          { age: 21, first_name: 'Larsen', last_name: 'Shaw' },
          { age: 89, first_name: 'Geneva', last_name: 'Wilson' },
          { age: 38, first_name: 'Jami', last_name: 'Carney' }
        ]
    }
  },
  computed: {
    activeFields(){
      return this.fields.filter(name => this.selected.includes(name))
    }
  }
}).$mount("#app");
```

```html
<!-- Add this to <head> -->

<!-- Load required Bootstrap and BootstrapVue CSS -->
<link type="text/css" rel="stylesheet" href="//unpkg.com/bootstrap/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css" />
<link type="text/css" rel="stylesheet" href="//unpkg.com/bootstrap-vue@latest/dist/bootstrap-vue.min.css" />

<!-- Load polyfills to support older browsers -->
<script src="//polyfill.io/v3/polyfill.min.js?features=es2015%2CIntersectionObserver" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>

<!-- Load Vue followed by BootstrapVue -->
<script src="//unpkg.com/vue@latest/dist/vue.min.js"></script>
<script src="//unpkg.com/bootstrap-vue@latest/dist/bootstrap-vue.min.js"></script>

<div id="app">
<b-form-group label="Hide columns: ">
  <b-form-checkbox-group id="checkbox-group-1" v-model="selected" :options="fields" name="flavour-1">
  </b-form-checkbox-group>
</b-form-group>


<b-table id="myTable" 
         
         :bordered="true"
         hover head-variant="dark"  
         stacked="md" 
         :items="items" 
         :fields="selected" 
         :current-page="currentPage"
         :per-page="perPage" 
         tbody-tr-class="row-class"
          v-if="selected.length > 0">
</b-table>
<b-table id="myTable" 
         
         :bordered="true"
         hover head-variant="dark"  
         stacked="md" 
         :items="items" 
         :fields="activeFields" 
         :current-page="currentPage"
         :per-page="perPage" 
         tbody-tr-class="row-class"
          v-if="selected.length > 0">
</b-table>
</div>
```

Comment: Could you please give me an example of how to make those fields static or fix my code if possible? I think I know what you're trying to say, but not really sure how to implement it

Comment: @FraneCaleta added something to sketch the idea

Comment: And where exactly should I use (call) that computed method I made? Sorry for so many questions, kinda new to Vue :<

Comment: @FraneCaleta in your vue component  like  cptItems and so on

Comment: So what I'm trying to do is adding:
columnNames = ["origin", "timestamp", "level", "loggerName", "direction", "thread", "actions"], 
Computed method like this:
cptTest() {
                let activeFields = columnNames.filter(name => selected.includes(name));
            }

And then in my bootstrap table adding :fields="cptTest" and also in checkbox group :options="activeFields".
I get error at columnNames --> invalid shorthand property initializer

Comment: And just do :fields="activeColumns"?
That doesn't seem to work either :((

Comment: @FraneCaleta i made you a working snippet with both versions ... :fields=selected & :fields=activeFields

Comment: Thanks a lot, it finally works! Now only problem I have is that those checkboxes are not pre-selected and that I can't add more options like I could before, for example: fields: [{
                  text: 'Origin',
                  value: {
                    key: 'origin',
                    label: 'Origin',
                    sortable: true,
                    class: 'text-center',
                    index: 0
                  }
                }... 
because now it looks like: fields: ['timeStamp', 'origin', 'level', 'loggerName', 'direction', 'thread', 'actions']

Comment: But you really helped me a lot already, so guess I can try to solve this somehow by myself and not waste your time anymore :)

Comment: @FraneCaleta i think you miss some major JavaScript skills - i suggest you to make some array and object mutation  examples (at)min 30 -  in SO: questions like how to sort  ... And so in ;) - you are welcome

Comment: Sorry for bothering you again, but if I try some mutations other stuff don't seem to work and I just don't know how to make those checkboxes pre-selected now when I've made it this way (it was pre selected before I implemented your changes). Could you please help me out since you know my app already? :<

Comment: Yes, I'm aware it's how it should work, but in my app it doesn't for some reason...

Comment: https://codepen.io/frane_caleta/pen/KKPgeva   ---> this is what I have right now (with your selected)

Comment: @FraneCaleta its blocked by codepen - email verification - 404